# cannot access outer class variable for datasnapshot.haschild() method

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[This is my datbase tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V5j0q.png)

the below is my code to check if my database has a child with a specified number stored in num variable.

i am unable to access num variable in addListenerForSingleValueEvent

here is my code.
Thanks in advance.

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();


public String nam,num;

 for( contacts e : mylist)
    {


        num = e.getPhoneNumber();
        nam = e.getName();

        check(nam,num);

    }
public void check(final String nam, final String num)
 {



     mDatabase.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
         @Override
         public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

             if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(num))  //this line is giving error
                 Toast.makeText(getActivity(),num,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }

         @Override
         public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

             Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"some error",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         }
     });
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference numberRef = rootRef.child(num);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if(dataSnapshot.exists()) {
            Log.d("TAG", "Number exists!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
numberRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

Comment: i have updated my question with picture of  my db structure , please check it and hope it helps u ..

Comment: no it isnt working , actually my code is  working if i explicity give any  number in db as datasnapshop.hasChild("+91...");  then its executing correctly and returning true.

Comment: This means that `num` variable is wrong. Check that please for me.

Comment: if i Toast that num in the same place ,its nicely printing all the numbers..so ,i think there is no issue with num variable

Comment: I figure it out. Move the declaration of `num = e.getPhoneNumber();` inside `onDataChange()` method. Will work 100%. It's right?

Comment: i moved it and its is asking to make e as final and i made it as final ... but it isnt working  as well.. but anyways thanks a lot , atleast i got to know many ways of pointing to a child in db

Comment: Should work with the variable as final. If you think that my answer helped you in any, please consider accepting it. Thanks!